# C++ getline(cin, variable) is misbehaving. No solutions on the site have helped

Tags: c++, getline

My code is rather simple. I have a method called `promptUserInput` that is defined in `UtilityFunctions.h`; it is implemented in `UtilityFunctions.cpp`.

My main method includes `UtilityFunctions.h`. I've correctly written my makefile, and it compiles without issue.

My main method's first line reads:

`string input = promptUserInput();`

And here's the actual implementation of the `promptUserInput` function:

```
/* Prompts user to enter expression */
string promptUserInput()
{
    string userInput;
    cout << "> ";   
    getline(cin, userInput);

    return userInput;
}
```

But when the program runs, it doesn't display the `>` symbol. Instead, there's an empty line waiting for user input. I enter some arbitrary character, hit Enter, and the `>` symbol appears afterwards. None of this makes sense to me. What's going on?

Comment: try `cout << "> " << flush;`

Comment: @M.M Nope, didn't work :(

Comment: try `cout << "> \n";`  . Of course you may not want a newline but it depends on the behaviour of the terminal you are running the program under whether that is possible.

Comment: Also post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's possible you're being misled by consequences of the previous input operations in the program

Comment: What do you mean by "previous input operations"? Just to clarify, the very first line in main is `string input = promptUserInput();`

Comment: You should show that in your question by posting a MCVE

Answer (score 2):

`std::cout` uses buffered output, which should always be flushed. You can achieve this by using `std::cout.flush()` or `std::cout << std::flush`.

You can also use `std::cout << std::endl`, which writes a line break and then flushes, but the line break might not satisfy your intention.